# Websocket with ActiveMQ support multi session?

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, stomp, spring-websocket

I have spring boot application use websocket and embeded ActiveMQ, when user **(TestUser)** subscribe **/user/TestUser/reply** in two different browser at the same time ,then send message to him one browser received the another not , send again new one the second receive but first one not and so on…… .

What I expected when send message to **/user/TestUser/reply**  , if he is open two browsers as the same time should receive the message in two browser at the same time.

POM.xml

```
<!-- WebSocket libraries -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
<artifactId>activemq-stomp</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
<artifactId>activemq-kahadb-store</artifactId>
<scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

WebSocketConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker 
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {


config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user")
.enableStompBrokerRelay("/user");

}


public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
registry.addEndpoint("/websocket").addInterceptors(new HttpHandshakeInterceptor()).withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
registration.setInterceptors(new TopicSubscriptionInterceptor());
}


@Bean
public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
broker.setSchedulePeriodForDestinationPurge(10000);
broker.addConnector("stomp://localhost:61613");
PolicyMap policyMap = new PolicyMap();
PolicyEntry policyEntry = new PolicyEntry();
policyEntry.setGcInactiveDestinations(true);
policyEntry.setInactiveTimeoutBeforeGC(30000);
policyEntry.setQueue(">");
List<PolicyEntry> entries = new ArrayList<PolicyEntry>();
entries.add(policyEntry);
policyMap.setPolicyEntries(entries);
broker.setDestinationPolicy(policyMap);
return broker;
}
```

UI

```
function connect() {
var socket = new SockJS('/websocket');
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
setConnected(true);
console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
stompClient.subscribe('/user/TestUser/reply', function (greeting) {
message = greeting;
showGreeting(greeting);

}, {'ack': 'client-individual'});
});
}
```

Comment: You can create **topic** /topic/reply/{userName} and subscribe/send to this topic. Every topic subscriber will receive any message sent to topic.

Comment: i can't understand can you explain with example @user1516873

Answer (score 0):

If you change your UI code to use topic, like this:

```
stompClient.subscribe('/topic/reply/'+ frame.headers['user-name'], function (greeting) { ...
```

and configure relay to /topic

```
config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
      .enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic");
```

and send messages like :

```
simpMessageTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/reply/" + principal, payload, headers);
```

than every connected client will recieve his message copy.

frame.headers['user-name'] some spring magic header with current logged in principal, returned on connect. don't know who adds it, maybe spring-security.

If you want to do it with anon user, you have to generate user-id on client side, store it somewhere ( localstorage or cookie ) and pass to server side to use as principal name.

EDIT:

If you want to restict connection to topic to only one user, you can do this like this (in TopicSubscriptionInterceptor):

```
@Override
public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
     StompHeaderAccessor sha = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
     switch (sha.getCommand()) {
          case SUBSCRIBE:
          case SEND:
              if(!sha.getDestination().equals("/topic/reply/" + sha.getUser().getName()) return null;
              break; 
     }
     ... 
     return message;
}
```

Comment: it's working ,  from security side anyone can subscribe to **/topic/reply/TestUser** ,so we have check if have principal to subscribe it' s correct ? and how can do this ?

Comment: the UI it's angular i get the user id contact with **/topic/reply/+userid**

Comment: Yes, sure you should restrict connection to topic, for example in TopicSubscriptionInterceptor.preSend method check topic name and principal name

Comment: also if send message to **TestUser** and he is disconnected after login (subscribe) the message send to him not arrive and any new message will send ?

Comment: i mean when he offline

Comment: Yes, it will not recieve any message if he is not subscribed to topic at the moment it sent. But I suppose you need some history in any case.

Comment: I 'am already use activemq embeded it's can solve this ? because my issue now more bigger from the multi session

Comment: Usually, history data stored in database, activemq not suited for this task well. It has duarable queue and topics, you can try go this way, but database is simplest approach.

Comment: can give example how can do some thing like this ? basically i need get to get user if offline , then save them in database, after this i need lisiner if offline user reconnected send messages from databse .... you have example  ?